# Running TextVectorization.adapt on a GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, text, deep-learning

I have a pretty large dataset with 3599999 columns, each row having text sentence with an average of 74 words. I am trying to use the [adapt](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization#adapt) function for a [Text Vectorization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization) layer but it is taking around 45 minutes to execute.

I switched the GPU runtime on in Google Colab, but while running `adapt()` the GPU does not seem to be utilized and it still takes around 45 minutes. Is there any way to run the adapt function specifically on the GPU?

For reference,

```
text_vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens = 10_000,
                                standardize="lower_and_strip_punctuation",
                                split="whitespace",
                                ngrams=None,
                                output_mode="int",
                                output_sequence_length=74)

text_vectorizer.adapt(train_sentences)
```

Comment: This does not mean it is not running on GPU, just that computation is not the bottleneck.

Comment: Actually when I check the Resource Utilization graph, CPU is the only one being used, GPU is in an idle state, so it should mean that it isn't running on the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

The book Deep Learning with Python says on page 318...

```
Importantly, because TextVectorization is mostly a dictionary lookup
operation, it can’t be executed on a GPU (or TPU), only on a CPU.
```